# Vue Liquor Tree - prevent collapse parent

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I need to select parent without collapsing children. I was trying use `event.preventDefault()` but it returns error "preventDefault is not a function".

```
<tree ref="tree" :data="templates" @node:collapsed="preventCollapsing" @node:selected="selectTemplate">
    <!-- ... -->
</tree>

//...
methods: {
  preventCollapsing(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  //...
}
```

There is any way to keep children expanded after clicked on parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The events only gives the selected / collapsed node as paremeter, not a preventable event object.

Looking at [the documentation](https://amsik.github.io/liquor-tree/#Component-Options), there is an option called `parentSelect` which is described by :

> By clicking node which has children it expands node. i.e we have two ways to expand/collapse node: by clicking on arrow and on text

And its default falue is `false`. Setting it to `true` should do it.

[Relevent source code](https://github.com/amsik/liquor-tree/blob/master/src/components/TreeNode.vue#L140)

Comment: I don't know how can I missed that, but I've read documentation many times and I don't saw it before :/ Thanks for help!